# image messes with side

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a website and I got an image centered in the middle over a video, but for some reason, the image messes with the width of the site. Can anyone help me fix this and/or know the problem? Thanks.

**with image**
[image]

**Without image**
[image]

```css
#contain {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
  z-index: -1;
}

#img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="img">
    <a style="color:white; font-family:verdana;" title="Home"><img src="purefilmsw.png" alt="Pure Films" width="912.5" height="58.5"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="vid"><video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted>
<source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `top: 0; left: 0;` to `#img`.

```css
#contain{
    position:relative;
}

video {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: fill;
 z-index: -1;
}

#img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <a style="color:white; font-family:verdana;" title="Home">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" width="912.5" height="58.5">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="vid">
  <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: it is still like before